# Inherited grails domain classes missing dynamic properties

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm having a problem where the related table id fields return 'null' from my domain objects when using inheritance. Here is an example:

In /src/groovy/

BaseClass1.groovy

```
class BaseClass1 {
    Long id
    static mapping = {
        tablePerConcreteClass true
    }
}
```

BaseClass2.groovy

```
class BaseClass2 extends BaseClass1 {
    String someOtherProperty
    static constraints = {
        someOtherProperty(maxSize:200)
    }
    static mapping = BaseClass1.mapping
}
```

In /grails-app/domain

ParentClass.groovy

```
class ParentClass extends BaseClass2 {
    ChildClass myChild

    static mapping = BaseClass2.mapping << {
        version false
    }
}
```

ChildClass.groovy

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass1 {
    String property

    static mapping = BaseClass1.mapping
}
```

The problem appears here:

SomeotherCode.groovy

```
print parentClassInstance.myChild.id // returns the value
print parentClassInstance.myChildId // returns null
```

Any ideas what might be going on to get those dynamic properties to break like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After debugging into the get(AssociationName)Id source, I found the following:
The handler for this is:

```
GrailsDomainConfigurationUtil.getAssociationIdentifier(Object target, String propertyName,
        GrailsDomainClass referencedDomainClass) {

    String getterName = GrailsClassUtils.getGetterName(propertyName);

    try {
        Method m = target.getClass().getMethod(getterName, EMPTY_CLASS_ARRAY);
        Object value = m.invoke(target);
        if (value != null && referencedDomainClass != null) {
            String identifierGetter = GrailsClassUtils.getGetterName(referencedDomainClass.getIdentifier().getName());
            m = value.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(identifierGetter, EMPTY_CLASS_ARRAY);
            return (Serializable)m.invoke(value);
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // ignore
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // ignore
    }
    catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // ignore
    }
    return null;
}
```

It threw an exception on the related class (value.getClass().getDeclaredMethod), saying NoSuchMethod for the method getId(). I was unable to remove the id declaration from the base class without Grails complaining that an identifier column was required. I tried marking id as public and it also complained that it wasn't there. So, I tried this

```
BaseClass {
    Long id
    public Long getId() { return this.@id }
}
```

and things worked on some classes, but not on others.

When I removed the ID declaration, I go an error: "Identity property not found, but required in domain class". On a whim, I tried adding @Entity to the concrete classes and viola! everything started working.

```
class BaseClass {
    //Don't declare id!
}

@Entity
class ParentClass {}

@Entity
class ChildClass {}
```

I still think it is a grails bug that it needs to be added, but at least it is easy enough to work around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are seeing this behavior, but I'm also not sure why you are doing some of the things you are doing here.  Why have a domain class extend a POGO?  Domains, Controllers, and Services are heavily managed by the Grails machinery, which probably was not designed for this sort of use.  Specifically, I believe Grails builds the dynamic property getters for the GrailsDomainProperty(s) of GrailsDomainClass(es), not POGO's.  In this case, you have an explicitly declared id field in BaseClass1 that is not a GrailsDomainProperty.  I suspect that this POGO id property is not picked up by the Grails machinery that creates the dynamic property getters for Domains.

You might try putting BaseClass1/2 in /grails-app/domain, perhaps making them abstract if you don't want them instantiated, then extending them as you are and seeing if you observe the behavior you want.

Comment: I've tried putting the base-est class into the domain folder, and both marking and not marking it as abstract. Grails started really giving me strange errors when I did that. I can try again to see what they were.

Comment: Extending base classes not in the domain folder is suggested in a number of places I've found online, especially if you don't want the base class to be made into a table. This is covered in the 2.x upgrade guide: http://www.grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/gettingStarted.html (#Abstract Inheritance Changes)